# Why isn't this frame in tkinter centered correctly?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pycharm, widget

I want this entry bar and other contents I'll add to the frame later to be centred correctly, I received this code that supposedly should work but it isn't.

```
import tkinter as tk
import math
import time

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text = "Exit", command = root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_entry = tk.Entry(root, width = 100, fg = "black")
main_entry.place(x=50, y=50)
frame.place(relx=.5,rely=.5, anchor='center')

root.mainloop()
```

As you can see the frame isn't centred so how can I fix this?

Comment: maybe add colors to backgrounds to see how it looks. Maybe Frame is centered but Entry is not centered.

Comment: `Frame` automatically changes size to size of objects inside `Frame` (when you use `pack()`) - but you have nothing inside `Frame` - you put all widgets directly in `root` - so it has no size (width zero, height zero) and it not visible. When I use `tk.Frame(root, bg='red', width=100, height=100)` then I see red frame in the center. BTW: if you want `Entry` inside `Frame` then use `tk.Entry(frame, ...)` instead of `tk.Entry(root, ...)`

Comment: so you have two problems: (1) you put `Entry` in wrong parent - it has to be `frame` instead of `root`, (2) you use `place()` which doesn't resize `Frame` to its children - and it has size zero.

Answer (score 1):

`Frame` automatically changes size to size of objects inside `Frame` (when you use `pack()`) but you have nothing inside `Frame`. You put all widgets directly in `root` - so `Frame` has no size (width zero, height zero) and it is not visible.

When I use `tk.Frame(root, bg='red', width=100, height=100)` then I see small red frame in the center.

You have two problems:

(1) you put `Entry` in wrong parent - it has to be `frame` instead of `root`,

(2) you use `place()` which doesn't resize `Frame` to its children and it has size zero - so you don't see it. You would have to set size of Frame manully (ie. `tk.Frame(..., width=100, height=100)`) or you could use `pack()` and it will resize it automatically.

I add colors for backgrounds to see widgets. `blue` for window and `red` for frame.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root['bg'] = 'blue'

root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.place(x=1506, y=0)

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='red')
frame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='center')

main_entry = tk.Entry(frame, width=100, fg="black")
main_entry.pack(padx=50, pady=50)  # with external margins 50

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve widget centering on a fullscreen I've had to use grid manager.
The code below works but the exact positioning requires some fiddling with frame padding.
frame padx = w/2-300 and pady = h/2-45 are arbitrary values found using a bit of trial and error.

```
    import tkinter as tk

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.attributes( '-fullscreen', True )
    w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()

    frame = tk.Frame( root )
    main_entry = tk.Entry( frame, width = 100 )
    main_entry.grid( row = 0, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW )
    frame.grid( row = 0, column = 0, padx = w/2-300, pady = h/2-45,  sticky = tk.NSEW )
    exit_button = tk.Button( frame, text = 'Exit', command = root.destroy )
    exit_button.grid( row = 1, column = 0, sticky = tk.NSEW )

    tk.mainloop()
```